# How do I fix this marlin error for the Professional-Ui software error?

Tags: github, probe, ender

The error is:

c:/users/caleb/.platformio/packages/toolchain-gccarmnoneeabi/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: Marlin/lib/proui\libproui.a(bed_tramming.cpp.o): in function `MarlinUI::set_status(char const*, bool)': D:\Users\Miguel\Documents\Trabajos\VSCode\Marlin_Ender3V2S1-Development/Marlin\src\lcd\e3v2\proui\../../marlinui.h:447: undefined reference to` BLTouch::high_speed_mode'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\STM32F103RC_creality\firmware.elf] Error 1

I think it has something to do with the probe settings, as I have a klackender probe, and after updating the firmware to match the setting for the probe, the error occurs.

I used the source files from this github:
https://github.com/mriscoc/Ender3V2S1/releases

I tried comparing the files to the Marlin bug fix and the original ProUi files, but I still had no luck. If you have any ideas, it would really help. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This question probably belongs on this site: https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/